# zdump and date do not show the same daylight saving information

Tags: date, timezone

I am using my localtime set to be Israel.

I updated the system clock and hardware clock, and using `zdump` I get:

```
~# zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Israel
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Israel  Wed Apr 20 16:11:36 2022 IDT
```

But, using `date` I get:

```
~ # date
Wed Apr 20 15:11:41 IST 2022
```

The correct form is of `zdump`, so `date` doesn't comply, and I want to know why.

I will also share `/etc` and `/tmp` content:

```
~ # ls -l /etc /tmp
/etc:
total 20631
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            30 Aug 11  2006 fs-version
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           128 Dec 18  2018 fstab
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000             9 Apr 19  2006 group
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           204 Dec 18  2018 hosts
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000          2048 Jan 10  2019 init.d
-rwxr--r--    1 1000     1000          3482 Sep 12  2019 inittab
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000          2048 Dec 18  2018 iproute2
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000          2048 Feb 21  2019 libnl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            14 Dec 18  2018 localtime -> /tmp/localtime
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           101 Apr 19  2006 mtab
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          2780 Dec 18  2018 ntp.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            25 Dec 18  2018 passwd
-rw-------    1 1000     1000            25 Dec 18  2018 passwd-
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          1882 Jan  1  1970 profile
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          2478 Feb 20  2006 protocols
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            16 Dec 18  2018 resolv.conf -> /tmp/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            20 Sep 12  2019 rootfs.version
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         15958 Feb 20  2006 services
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000          2048 Dec 18  2018 ssl
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1736 Jan 13  1970 syslog.conf
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            13 Dec 18  2018 timezone -> /tmp/timezone
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000          2048 Dec 20  2018 udev

/tmp:
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            26 Apr 20 15:10 localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Israel
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            46 Apr 20 15:10 resolv.conf
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            80 Apr 20 15:10 run
drwxr-x---    6 root     root           160 Apr 20 15:10 sx-web
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             7 Apr 20 15:10 timezone
```

Why is the difference in Daylight Saving and how can I correct it?

Comment: Probably, it would be useful to add some more information. Your OS, if your box is configured to synchronize with an NTP server, and if the time is displayed correctly or not outside the shell.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Copied from question into an answer.)</sup>

Fixed by updating Busybox to a newer version. Thanks @thanasisp, by looking for more info I fixed the issue.